# Parameters and functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, vector

Let's suppose this code:

```
void function(const float vect[]){

// making something with "vect" here (not modifying as it is const)

};
```

then in the main function:

```
float v[5];

function(v+2);
```

Is it correct to call the function like that?
What exactly I'm passing to that function doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to call the function like that?

As long as you don't access the array out of bounds (i. e. you only read `vect[0]`, `vect[1]` or `vect[2]`), it is.

> What exactly I'm passing to that function doing that?

I don't understand this question. If you want to know what this does: the `v` array decays into a pointer, then the `+` operator performs pointer arithmetic on it, and a pointer to of the third element (i. e. the one at index 2) is passed to the function.

Answer (score 2):

The array will decay to pointer during the call

so you're basically doing this :-

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
 ^    ^   ^   ^   ^
 |    |   |   |   |
 v   v+1 v+2 v+3 v+4
          ^
          |
function(v+2); //In "function" v will be used from v+2, i.e. vect[0] will be v[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand this you have to understand that sometimes C++ lies.

`void function(const float vect[]){` is not a function taking an array as a parameter (that's the lie). Instead it's exactly the same as if you had written this `void function(const float* vect){`. Now it's easier to understand, your function takes a pointer, so when you write `function(v+2);` you are passing a pointer to the third element of your array, just as when you write `function(v);` you are passing a pointer to the first element of your array.

It's impossible to pass an array to a function in C++ (or return an array from a function), arrays are always converted into pointers in these situations.

Comment: In C++, it's actually possible to pass an array if you pass it by reference. That's rare, though, and it still doesn't permit pure pass by value.

Comment: Yes but technically it's not really "passing an array" as in "the array ends up on your stack"

Comment: @KevinCadieux Technically, it **is** "passing an array". There's no notion of a stack per se in C++.

Comment: Although the function signature is relevant, that's not why `v` is converted to a pointer before the addition. Arrays in C++ (and C) just have a tendency to convert to pointers in a lot of cases, and the plus operator can add an integer to a pointer (offsetting the pointer by that number of items), but can't add an integer to an array.

Comment: @H2CO3 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83ab6f757e33a466 I had the wrong link before.

Comment: @KevinCadieux Um, of course, and an `int` is not the same as a reference to `int`. Still, my point is that when you pass an object by reference, then you pass the object itself. References aren't pointers. So, if you pass a reference to an array, then you pass the array itself. It won't decay into a pointer, it won't do anything weird -- it will just stay what it is, a nice, little, innocent **array.** No wonder C++'s type system is in contradiction with its semantics (i. e. a reference is the object itself but its type is not the same). Stupid C++ designers.

Comment: @H2CO3 "when you pass an object by reference, then you pass the object itself". Yes but you pass it... "by reference". No bytes get moved other than what is needed to reference the actual memory location where the object resides. But I see your point now. It's just that to me, passing an object depends on what actually gets moved in terms of memory and the actual type.

Comment: @KevinCadieux You're right in that it is pretty much how the human brain grasps it. Unfortunately, that and the definition of the language don't match (another reason why programming is sometimes hard). :)

Comment: @H2CO3 So you are saying that in the standard it is directly stated that passing a reference is like passing the object itself? According to what I have read, there seems to be a clear difference between these two concepts, enough to distinguish an object from its reference. In fact (N3337 3 p3) classifies references and objects as different entities. Also, (N3337 8.3.2 p4) admits the possibility that references might require their own memory, and the note in (N3337 8.3.2 p1) distinguishes a reference as being the name of an object, and not the object itself.

Comment: This seems to uphold the view that a reference is a reference, and not the object itself.

Comment: But I guess you mean from a use case point of view, they are the same. Anyway, all of this is not that important :)

Comment: @KevinCadieux They are of *different type.* A reference type is a reference type. So, sure, `int (&arrRef)[5]` is not the same as `int arr[5]`. However, when you are accessing an object through a reference, really you are accessing the object itself. There's no "un-reference" (I intentionally don't use the word "dereference") operator, because an object of reference type behaves exactly like an object of its base type. If C++ didn't have this strict distinction in its type system, this would be transparent (imagine a language in which function arguments are implicitly passed byref) (cont)

Comment: (cont) This is why I am saying that this is a contradiction in the type system. It's unintuitive, that's all.

Comment: Yeah okay, we're on the same page then :)

Comment: WRT an earlier phase of this discussion - I would say that the intent of pass-by-reference is implemented using the idiom of passing reference values by value, so whether the array is passed or not is a viewpoint thing. C++ doesn't have pass-by-reference as a language feature, it only has pass-by-value. It's just that some of the values you might pass are references (or pointers). But in terms of programmer intent, it's still perfectly valid to say you're passing by reference, and therefore that you're passing the array.